# Saving dates in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

When saving dates in a Database I have always believed that it is better to save dates with the numbers of the *time()* function as it is more accurate but I have also seen people saving dates like that *2013-02-01*.

Which one is recommended? Or are there different occasions whether you should use one or the other?

Comment: This is really an opinion poll, I'd say. But if you store them as a numeric representation you have to convert it back into a date to do anything useful. Maybe you should keep all string data as a byte array, no?

Comment: either way you save it, it depends on what u will do with the data. mysql has a TIMESTAMP field which will save the year month day hour minute second. this can be converted to a date in PHP.

Comment: i think time is better because  number need little space for saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather save dates as `DATE` rather than `INT` because:

- more readable
- it is still date!

anyway it is still your option, consider this,

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), CURDATE()
```

will result

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())   CURDATE()
1359676800                  2013-02-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Always save as textual representations of dates, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`. Easier to read by humans, and not limited to the limits of Unix timestamp integers (you can only go so far forward or so far back with integers).

Answer (score 0):

It would be conservative to standardize on ISO 8601, and a lot easier than translating to and from the time_t UNIX epoch.

Start of the next day can be affected by the hour offset, so there can be issues with time zones.  While in Daylight Saving Time, the start of the day can be affected.  Using time_t *might* disambiguate these issues, but it might also fall into a problem because you did not translate the time_t correctly for your intended effect.

Since the UNIX time epoch has a time component, this could be a problem if you send the time_t value and have the database translate it into a date.  The database could translate it in a way you didn't expect.  However, if you send a date, the database will take you at your word, store that date (irrespective of the timezone it thinks that date is in) and return that exact date.

Now, such a translation problem could happen depending on how you get the date value you included in your SQL.  However, that would be a problem in your code, and you could expect the database to not have translated or changed the value you sent it.

I'd stick with entering it as a date because it is readable, it is a date, it won't have any more problems than time_t had even if the problems happen under different circumstances.